# change POST url on the fly during HTTP request in Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon

I would like to change url the HTTP POST to during the request in firefox. Currently I have tried "Tamper Data" firefox addon which allows me change POST parameters but not the POST request url during the request.

I don't want to mimic the post by curl etc as I have to manually setup the cookie and parameters all that.

Is there such thing available in firefox?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) addon.
There is a "Replay" button where you can alter URL and data of a previously recorded request.

Comment: Deprecated in the latest version of firefox